# Is it possible to define the generalized Jacobian of a curve when the modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ is supported on points of higher degree?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, generalized-jacobians

The book *Algebraic groups and class fields* by Serre explains a lot about the construction of the generalized Jacobian $J_\mathfrak{m}$ of a smooth projective curve $X$ with respect to the modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

An interesting case is when we identify $n+1$ closed points of $X$ to obtain the singular curve $X'$ with an $(n+1)$-fold singular point $Q$. Let $P_0,...,P_n$ be the points identified and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be supported on these points, with $n_i=1$ for each $P_i$. Then we have an embedding $X' \setminus \{Q\} \hookrightarrow J_\mathfrak{m}$, which is a semiabelian variety sitting in the (strict) exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_m^n \rightarrow J_\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow J \rightarrow 0,$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian variety of $X$.

One naturally asks if we can define $J_\mathfrak{m}$ when our base field $k$ is not algebraically closed. Suppose $k$ has characteristic zero. The book then says this on page 105:

> Let $X$ be a curve defined over $k$ and let $\mathfrak{m}$ be a modulus on $X$; we will suppose that $\mathfrak{m}$ is *rational* over $k$ (cf. Chapter 1). Since $k$ is perfect, this means only that the points of the support $S$ of $\mathfrak{m}$ are algebraic over $k$ and that $\mathfrak{m}^\sigma = \mathfrak{m}$ for every element $\sigma$ belonging to the Galois group of $\bar{k}/k$.

I would first say that nowhere in Chapter 1 was a definition of $rational$ modulus being given. I'm confused by what this paragraph is saying. Does it want to say that since $k$ is perfect, **rationality** means that the points of the support $S$ of $\mathfrak{m}$ are algebraic over $k$ and that $\mathfrak{m}^\sigma = \mathfrak{m}$ for every element $\sigma$ belonging to the Galois group of $\bar{k}/k$?

If this is indeed the case, then if our chosen points $P_i$ are all $k$-rational it would immediately satisfy the condition. However, what happens if some points are not $k$-rational, i.e., they have degree $>1$, is there a way to still define $J_\mathfrak{m}$ over $k$?

Comment: The correct citation in Serre is not "cf. Chapter 1" but "cf. $\S 1$", in the same chapter (I have the French edition). That being said your interpretation is correct. Moreover, the support $S = \{P_0,\ldots,P_n\}$ must be Galois invariant in order to be able to define the generalised Jacobian over $k$.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault Oh yes I just realised... I've found it, it's written on page 75 of the book, pointers (i) and (ii). So I guess the answer is no, that there is no known way of defining the generalized Jacobian over $k$ if the support is not Galois invariant.